# How to add 5 buttons in center by using border layout?

Tags: java, layout

I wonder how to add 5 buttons in center that already made by border layout.
The result I want to get is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSqjW.png)

(The color of the center is to make clear what I want to add)

The code that I already wrote is:

```
 public class FiveButtons extends JFrame {
        protected JButton c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;


        public FiveButtons( ) {
            super("보더 레이아웃");


          c1=new JButton("Center");
            c2=new JButton("South");
            c3=new JButton("North");
            c4=new JButton("West");
            c5=new JButton("East");



            getContentPane().add(c1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            getContentPane().add(c2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            getContentPane().add(c3,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            getContentPane().add(c4,BorderLayout.WEST);
            getContentPane().add(c5,BorderLayout.EAST);



            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(300,200);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FiveButtons fb=new FiveButtons();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Create snippet only for HTML, CSS and JS code.

Comment: you can use Jpanel and add c1,c2,c3,c4 and c5 to jpanel and then add Jpanel to center of borderLayout .I think this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your button into a unique component, since a BorderLayout "zone" only accept 1 component. Use a JPanel to be that unique component.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.add(c1);
panel.add(c2);
panel.add(c3);
panel.add(c4);
panel.add(c5);

getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

NOTE : This is using the `FlowLayout` by default, you can update it if you need